# Error message 'Expected ; after top level declarator ' 'Unknown type name import' with a framework add in package Futter

Tags: c++, xcode, flutter

I try to use a framework write in C++11 in a Flutter package. The framework is linked with the configuration on my podspec, so now I want to import Header file of the framework C++ to use in my package Flutter and run tis to the iOs. But when I try to import this

`#import <DemoFramwork/DemoFrameworkGlobal.h>`

I have this error **Error message 'Expected ; after top level declarator ' 'Unknown type name import'**

```
//A part code of DemoFrameworkGlobal.h
enum class RXSDemo{
  exemplA, exampleB, exampleC
};

struct RXSDemoResponse {
   bool result;
   double angleX, angleY;
   double minAngleX, maxAngleX, minAngleY, maxAngleY;
};
@interface DemoComm : NSObject
-(NSString*)getDemo;
-(XSDemo)initCommExample:(NSString*)token;
```

Etc...

Thx to help me :))

Comment: there is no `#import` in C++, is this a marco coming from the framework? did you mean `#include` ?

Comment: `#import` is Objective-C(++), and so is the code in your question.